# How to specify a docker container database to a app running in docker with docker-compose.yml?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mediawiki

### Context

There is this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mediawiki:
    image: mediawiki
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/images
      # After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
      # this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
      # the mediawiki service
      # - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
  database:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      # @see https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/browse/master/includes/DefaultSettings.php
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_wiki
      MYSQL_USER: wikiuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
```

When I run `docker ps` I get:

```
89db8794029a  mysql:latest "docker-entrypoint..."  ...  0.0.0.0:8083->3306/tcp   some-mysql
```

This is a mysql docker container running.

### Question

How can I modify the `docker-compose.yml` in a way that the database to point to the mysql docker container (89db8794029a) already running?

Comment: ?  you can't point to a container unless they are all part of the same docker network.  Are you running two containers?  And you can't bind 8080 or 80 on a database they use 3306

Comment: So then, I first make a docker network? The mysql container runs on port 8083 on my machine and I want the mediawiki app to use the mysql container

Comment: I'm confused, why are you doing such things like moving around the mysql port?  This might be beyond how I can help you

Comment: the yml file when run, it creates its own database based on mariadb image. What I want is that the app not to create its database but to use an already working mysql database which is exposed by 8083, but the mysql database works internaly on 3306.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to add the database service on the yml file.

In order mediawiki service connect to some-mysql container, the mediawiki container need to be on a same network with some-mysql container

assuming that the mediawiki already up

first, you need to know what network some-mysql use,

```
docker network ls
```

i'm guessing it would be 'some-mysql_default'

to connect media wiki to some-mysql

```
docker network connect some-mysql_default mediawiki
```

now, use 'some-mysql' as hostname database in mediawiki config

OR

yml file to automatically connect to mysql network

```
version: '3'
services:
  mediawiki:
    image: mediawiki
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/images
      # After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
      # this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
      # the mediawiki service
      # - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
    networks:
      - default
      - some-mysql_default
networks:
  default: # this network
    driver: bridge
  some-mysql_default: # external network
    external: true
```